# Which Ubuntu flavor?

Tags: lubuntu, compiling, performance, battery, ubuntu-gnome

I have a HP 255 G3 (specs can be found [here](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-255-g3-15-6-a-series-a4-6210-windows-7-pro-64-bit-windows-8-1-pro-downgrade-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd-g4v03uaaba/specs/)) And I can't decide what Ubuntu flavor to install into it, vanilla, Gnome or Lubuntu, because I don't know the core differences in them. (The DE differences are clear, but I'm not certain if it's the only thing that affects performance or battery life, or are there some deeper changes.) Battery life and performance are important, but they can be sacrificed, if stuff will work more smoothly. I've used all of them and that's why this is so hard.

Here's my pros and con's on every platform:

- Ubuntu: The laptop will be a school / coding platform, so pure Ubuntu
  would be nice to use, so I can be certain that stuff I need will work
  on it (Apps that I use in school and libraries I use to compile) BUT
  I don't really like the unity environment and pure Ubuntu isn't the
  best with battery nor performance.
- Gnome: I like the desktop, a lot... But Gnome is worse with
  performance and battery and I've had problems with it on my desktop,
  while trying to compile stuff. (I'm not sure if the fault is in stuff
  I've done or the environment)
- Lubuntu: Great with battery, great with performance. I've used it a
  lot in the past, but I don't know if it'll work with the apps I need
  to use or the code I'm compiling.

Of course, mixing would be great, but I don't know where the effects start or end. Optimally I would end up with Gnomes desktop installed on top of Lubuntu / Ubuntu.

I thought, this might actually be important:
The code I'm trying to compile >at the moment< is busybox, but getting that to work should be on a different question, I think ;)
The apps I need to work are libre office (which isn't hard) and some weird programs from the school, that I don't have access to. They've only told me that they can be used on Ubuntu, but I don't know if they'll work right on different flavors.

Comment: That's a capable machine that can run any flavor of Ubuntu. Your programs should work just fine on any of the Ubuntu flavors. If you like GNOME, you can go with Ubuntu GNOME -- it'll work great on that machine. Or if you like KDE you could try out Kubuntu. If you want something a little more lightweight (but still fully-featured) you could go with Ubuntu MATE (my favorite!!!) or Xubuntu; Lubuntu is even lighter but lacks some features. Overall, it's mostly about personal preference; like I said, any of your programs should work. The great thing about any Ubuntu flavor is you can try it first!

Comment: You didn't mention Xubuntu in your post. Xubuntu is a reasonable compromise between Lubuntu and, say, Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: 'They've only told me that they can be used on Ubuntu, but I don't know if they'll work right on different flavors.' And why are you asking us about it?!? Ask your school about it! We are no psychic! We can't hack into your school's PCs and find out what that piece of software is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME is my choice, definetly works with your specs as far as performance and battery is no problem.

Try it, does worth it and you get nautilus instead of unity and ubuntu GNOME is very efficient take a look:

[Ubuntu Gnome tweaks](https://www.linux.com/learn/easy-steps-make-gnome-3-more-efficient)

Comment: I installed vanilla Ubuntu and gnome desktop on top of it. I get to use the desktop I love and can be sure that stuff works. I'll might give unity 8 and mir a go later on. Thanks for the answer and the link!

Answer (score 1):

Plain vanilla Ubuntu will run just fine on that machine.  Battery and performance are at least as good as with Ubuntu Gnome (despite what you may have read in a forum on the Internet).

Once you're used to Unity you'll find the 1990s-style desktop UIs are clunky and hard to use.

Comment: I've used all the flavors listed above, even on that very machine, and have experience on each one of them. GNOME is my favorite at the moment, because it looks the cleanest and can be themed easy. ( One might argue, that the themes even look better on GNOME) I don't like Unity as it is right now, but we'll see what 8 will bring to the table ;) I might have another try with gnome installed atop of ubuntu, but so far xubuntu seems like the best choice. Mate and KDE simply aren't my cups of tea ;) (I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have 15 reputation on this side of stack exchange yet)